# Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.1.1:5432

Tags: postgresql, firebase, knex.js

good day all, i am working with knex, postgresql and firebase and I created a postgres sever in pgadmin and I am try to connect to it, to run normal crud operations, but anytime I run the API in my postman, it shows this error:

```
>  {"verifications":{"app":"MISSING","auth":"MISSING"},"logging.googleapis.com/labels":{"firebase-log-type":"callable-request-verification"},"severity":"INFO","message":"Callable request verification passed"}
i  functions: Finished "bookDate" in ~1s
>  Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.1.1:5432
>      at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1247:16) {
>    errno: -111,
>    code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
>    syscall: 'connect',
>    address: '127.0.1.1',
>    port: 5432
>  }
```

this is my connection in my .env:

```
DB_URL=postgres://postgres:123@127.0.1.1/wheboo
```

the ipaddress, name and password is the same as the host in pgadmin:
[image: pgadmin]

so I don't understand what the problem is.
this is the code I'm trying to write:

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
require("dotenv").config({ path: '../.env' });
const db = require("./db.js");


exports.bookDate =
  functions
    .region('europe-west2')
    .https.onCall((data, context) => {
      db('users').select()
        .then(function (result) {
          console.log("result")
          return {
            status: 200,
            success: true,
            message: result
          };
        })
        .catch((e)=>{
          console.log(e)
        })

      


    });
```

Comment: Is pgAdmin running on the same server as your app server is?  127.0.1.1 will mean different things depending on what computer your are on.  And what part of this is on Google Cloud?

Comment: I'm on a windows pc, I don't know if it's running on the same server, and there is no significant part of the code that uses google cloud, I am just using firebase functions

Comment: Have you tried to set the port number like this `DB_URL=postgres://postgres:123@127.0.1.1:5432/wheboo`

Comment: run: `service postgresql status` cmd and check wheather your server is online or not.

Answer (score -1):

Where does your pgadmin run? If it runs on the same host as the postgres database, then 127.0.0.1 is correct from its perspective.
You should use the hostname of pgadmin in this case. And if that does not work look for the database hostname in the firebase settings.

If your pgadmin host is `pgadmin-host.xyz` then try this:

`DB_URL=postgres://postgres:123@pgadmin-host.xyz/wheboo`